# Ошибка "No such file or directory" silero python

Tags: python, pytorch, silero

Писал программу, которая озвучивает текст на библиотеке `silero`

**Пример кода с документации:**

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
from time import sleep

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v4_ru'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'xenia'
device = torch.device('cpu')

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language=language,
                                     speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)  # gpu or cpu

audio = model.apply_tts(text=example_text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate)
```

При первом запуске идёт долгая загрузка голосовой модели, после чего выдаёт ошибку:

```
Using cache found in C:\Users\Кирилл/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\voice\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 566, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 595, in _load_local  
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 87, in silero_tts       
    imp = package.PackageImporter(model_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\package\package_importer.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.zip_reader = torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(self.filename)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen: No such file or directory, file path: C:\Users\Кирилл/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\model\v4_ru.pt
```

**Казалось бы, в "директории отсутствует файл"**, но нет, голосовую модель он загружает нормально, и сама директория к ней тоже верная
[image: директория]

---

### Как я выяснил:

Эта ошибка появляется т.к в директории содержится **кириллица**, поэтому надо изменить название папки пользователя, но это делать очень сложно. Видел на форумах, что для этого нужно создавать отдельного пользователя и редактировать реестр, но люди пишут что после этого летят учётки, а сидеть со второго пользователя только ради одной програмки тоже не хочется. Или можно как-нибудь изменить директорию загрузки голосовых моделей.

**Возможно ли как-то просто и без риска сменить название папки учётной записи или изменить директорию загрузки голосовых моделей?**

Comment: Ну да, с кириллицей в путях реально проблемы часто бывают. Как лечить не подскажу, но скорее всего да, из-за этого.

Comment: Можно например через переменные окружения настроить другой путь к папке `.cache`. См. [How to modify path where Torch Hub models are downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59134499/4752653)